# drawing diagram for binary relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

im working on the practice problem on unit about sets and relations The question is: Let a = {1,2,3,4} and R be a binary relation on A x A given by: ((a,b),(c,d)) ∈R if and only if a divides c and b divides d. Draw its diagram.

Im having a trouble figuring how to draw the diagram because I was never taught how to draw it.. I assume that I should start with (1,1) at the most bottom and place (1,2),(1,3),(1,4) above it and so on.

Little help will be very much appreciated Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have a set with 16 elements, so you need to draw 16 points on the plane and join *some* of them with arcs. The trick is *not* to draw too many arcs - for example, you'll need to draw an arc between (1, 1) and (1, 2) and another arc between (1, 2) and (2, 2), but you *shouldn't* draw an arc between (1, 1) and (2, 2) because of transitivity (which I think you'll need to prove):

$$(1, 1) \le (1, 2) \le (2, 2)$$

So, the total number of arcs won't be too many, and your drawing will be quite understandable.